# what is the best activation function for binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, conv-neural-network, activation-function

i'm beginner in cnn and i want to detect which one is genuine image and which one is spoof image. i got really confused to choose my activation function. for binary classifiers, should i choose sigmoid or softmax ? any answer would be appreciate it. thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean at the very end (it seems like you do), it is determined by your data. Since you want to do a binary classification of real vs spoof, you pick sigmoid. Softmax is a generalization of sigmoid when there are more than two categories (such as in MNIST or dog vs cat vs horse).

When there are only two categories, the softmax function *is* the sigmoid function, though specifying a softmax function instead of sigmoid may confuse the software you’re using. You can prove this from the definition of softmax.

(Sigmoid and softmax need not use $e$ as the base, so saying “the” sigmoid or softmax function is not 100% correct. However, $e$ as the base is common and likely to be the default in whatever software you’re using.)

Comment: yes, i mean at the very end. base on yout explanation i think the sigmoid is suite for my dataset. thank you for answer

Comment: I think it would be a good exercise for you to prove that sigmoid is a special case of softmax. It will help you see why the distinction doesn’t matter except for how software interprets those commands (expecting 3+ categories if you tell it to use softmax, and only having two categories like you do may surprise your software).